# Crash after a popToRootViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, crash, uitabbarcontroller, nszombie

I have a crash when trying to switch to another VC.
Here is the structure:

TabBarController [Home, Tab2, Result tab]

from these tabs, I can push a new viewController called addVC which contains a `UITextField`.

What I want to do, is to be able to follow this sequence:
Tab2/Home (step1) => addVC (step2) => Result tab (step3)

To do this, I use this code in addVC :

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
UITabBarController *tabbarController = ((UITabBarController*)appDelegate.window.rootViewController);
[tabbarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

It works most of the time, but if the focus was in the textfield when I pop then push the result tab, the tab from the step1 is no longer accessible without a crash.

The crash log is:

```
[addVC respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x10977e60
```

NSZombie tells me that [UITextField canBecomeFirstResponder] has been called, causing the crash.

Since I use a storyboard, nothing except this is done programmatically. I guess my way to go to step3 is not the right one.
I'm using ARC and I'm not releasing anything by myself.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who could have the same problem, the solution was to use this:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Before popping anything, else the keyboard is still displayed and that's what causes the crash.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  `[self.navigationController popToViewController:orderEntry animated:YES];
             [[[[[self tabBarController]tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:1] setBadgeValue:@"1"];
            [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:(OrderBookViewController*)[[self.tabBarController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:1]];
            [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];`